# How to simply remove the character of non nested text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Current HTML:

```
<span>
    <a href="www.blue-world.pl">link</a>
    text with addional dot at the ened to remove.
</span>
```

I need to remove the last `.` in text node.

Comment: use `replace(".", " ");`

Comment: Will the `.` be last character of the string? Can it be multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('span').contents().get().forEach(function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/\.\n$/, '')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
    <a href="www.blue-world.pl">link</a>
    text with addional dot at the ened to remove.
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

this will remove only the last dot whereever it is

```
$('span').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
     var str = this.textContent;
     var pos = str.lastIndexOf('.');
     str = str.substring(0,pos) + str.substring(pos+1);
     this.textContent = str;
});
```

Comment: This will strip all the HTML from the `span`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan made the change to replace only the last dot, please have a look.

Comment: The updated code still has the same issue. You cannot use `text()` to achieve this as it will remove all the HTML within the element: https://jsfiddle.net/tyrbf8md/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what about now? Sorry last time I totally forgot about other html content.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for pointing out mistakes, appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you for taking it constructively - glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove text like this

```
jQuery("span").text().slice(".",-1);
```

Comment: This will strip all the HTML from the `span`.

Comment: ... because your code will remove all the HTML from the span, not just the last `.`. It also won't change the text as you're only getting the value.